# Multiply two chars and return int to array

Tags: c++, arrays

So Im trying to build a code for multipling two numbers of two arrays..
for example 
array 1 : 1 2 3
array 2 : 4 5 6
so i can return array 1 as : 4 10 18

```
BigNumber BigNumber::Multiply(const BigNumber & b)

float x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    x = (arr[i])*(b.arr[i]);
        arr[i] = (x / 48);
}


return *this;
```

it keeps giving me a +1 or -1 of the wanted result.

Comment: Why on earth `float` is used for storeing results of integer multplication? (assuming `arr` is array of `char` from the title)

Comment: Ive tried with INT aswell, arr[i] are chars

Comment: `arr[i]*=b.arr[i]`?

Comment: BTW. Why are you dividing `x` by `48`?

Comment: Because ARR[I] = char and I have to convert and print it as a INT

Comment: The result was +1 or -1? [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/twoF9626M4juswJe).

Comment: "Ive tried with INT aswell, arr[i] are chars" - This reply to the "why use float" comment, tells me that you are just guessing and don't actually *know* what you are doing. You *cannot* program by guesswork. You *have* to learn the rules and then apply them deliberately - everything else is just going to end up as a major cluster-fuck of a horrible maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Note that none of the parentheses in the code inside the loop body are needed.

Comment: Read about `std::transform`.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation inside the loop is wrong.

Let me use `ai` to represent the number represented by character `a` and like this `bi` corresponding to `b`.

Assuming 48 is used to represent character 0, your calculation is

```
  (ai+48)*(bi+48)/48
= (ai*bi)/48 + (ai+bi) + 48
```

This seems addition, not multiplication.

Try using a simple correct expression like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    arr[i] =  (arr[i]-'0') * (b.arr[i]-'0') + '0';
}
```